# Password reset block in cms page going to 404 after submit

Tags: blocks, cms

I'm trying to create a custom password reset page.  I placed the following page in a cms page:

```
{{block type="customer/form_login" template="customer/form/reset_password.phtml"}}
```

When submitting form, it goes to a 404 page.  Assuming it has to do something with the action in form on reset_password.phtml:

```
action="<?php echo $this->getUrl('*/*/forgotpasswordpost') ?>"
```

How do I correctly process this form?

Answer (score 2):

That block has `getForgotPasswordUrl()` available

See: https://github.com/OpenMage/magento-mirror/blob/magento-1.9/app/code/core/Mage/Customer/Block/Form/Login.php#L73

Comment: I understand I can link to the default forgotpassword.phtml, however, I am trying to create an additional custom page.

Comment: This action ended up working for me: `<?php echo Mage::getUrl('customer/account/forgotpasswordpost') ?>`

Answer (score 2):

Try

```
{{block type="customer/account_forgotpassword" template="customer/form/reset_password.phtml"}}
```

The form need to be posted to the correct url which is define in the block type